# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client cascade delete not working

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, cascade, cascading-deletes

For our project we store data in the Oracle DB. And use database first approach to build our model.

We have 2 tables of business entities and third one that creates many to many relation between them.

[image]

It so happened that mapping table has extra field besides foreign keys to the main tables.
As I understood from the EF documentation if mapping table did not have that extra field then EF would just “hide” mapping table from the model and would create direct reference collection from one business entity to another. But not in our case.

May be it is because of the extra field or maybe because of the oracle provider that we use “Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client” but on a delete Entity framework generates incorrect order of the delete statements.
Even though I’ve set up cascade delete for the association in the model and database foreign key constraint also has cascade delete rule.

```
=============== BEGIN COMMAND ===============
delete "X"."SCORECARD"
where (("SCORECARDID" = :p0) and ("DATE_CHANGED" = :p1))
:p0 = test1      
:p1 = 5/30/2014 2:52:55 PM
=============== END COMMAND ===============

=============== BEGIN COMMAND ===============
delete "X"."SCORECARD_CATEGORY"
where (("SCORECATEGORYID" = :p0) and ("SCORECARDID" = :p1))
:p0 = DB3 
:p1 = test1      
=============== END COMMAND ===============

=============== BEGIN COMMAND ===============
delete "X"."SCORECARD_CATEGORY"
where (("SCORECATEGORYID" = :p0) and ("SCORECARDID" = :p1))
:p0 = DB4 
:p1 = test1      
=============== END COMMAND ===============
```

Can you please suggest what should I check/change/add/delete whatever in order to make it work correctly?